# python: pivoting data with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having some data in excel which i am able to read into a dataframe. Now i have to convert this data into a said format.

source data-
[image]

Target data-

[image]

- total amount should go under category Total
- category amount should go under category category
- dept amount should go under category dept
- case amount should only align with category total

I am trying with stack but yet to achieve the target format.

any help will be highly appreciated.

here is code for creating source dataframe-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100,'all',None,None,None,None,None,None,100,101],
              [101,'east',7991,212,122,212,112,345,432,565],
              [102,'west',989,327,None,None,323,656,215,646]],
             columns = ['id_num','desc','total_sal1','total_sal2','category1_1','category1_2','dept1_1','dept1_2','case1','case2']
             )
```

df

Regards

Comment: Please, post your source data as text. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `(101, east, dept)` should be `amount1=112` and `amount2=345`?

Comment: There is one more way of doing that (using stack)

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1) Using `wide_to_long`:

I am renaming the columns as `total1, total2, category1, category2` etc by using regex so that I can use the `wide_to_long` and will split by `""`
If have `total_1, .. category_2` I would have split by `"_"`

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\d*_.*(?=\d)', '', regex=True)
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

res = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['total', 'category', 'dept'], 
                i=['id_num', 'desc', 'case1', 'case2'], j='categories', suffix='.*', sep='')
 .unstack().stack(level=0).add_prefix('amount')).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4':'categories'})

res.loc[res.categories.ne('total'), ['case1', 'case2']]= np.nan
```

---

| categories | id_num | desc | case1 | case2 | categories | amount1 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | all | NaN | NaN | category | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 100 | all | NaN | NaN | dept | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 100 | all | 100.0 | 101.0 | total | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 101 | east | NaN | NaN | category | 122.0 | 212.0 |
| 4 | 101 | east | NaN | NaN | dept | 112.0 | 345.0 |
| 5 | 101 | east | 432.0 | 565.0 | total | 7991.0 | 212.0 |
| 6 | 102 | west | NaN | NaN | category | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 102 | west | NaN | NaN | dept | 323.0 | 656.0 |
| 8 | 102 | west | 215.0 | 646.0 | total | 989.0 | 327.0 |

---

### Method 2) Using `stack`:

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.set_index(['id_num', 'desc', 'case1', 'case2'], inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\d*_.*(?=\d)', '-', regex=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("-", expand=True)
df = df.stack(level=0).add_prefix('amount').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4':'categories'})
df.loc[res.categories.ne('total'), ['case1', 'case2']]= np.nan
```

---

### Method 3) Using `apply` and `groupby`:

```
import numpy as np
import string 

def w2l(grp):
    res = grp.T
    cols = res.columns[0].split('_')[0]

    res.columns = ['amount1', 'amount2']

    res = res.reset_index()
    res['category'] = cols.rstrip(string.digits)
    if not ('total' in cols):
        res['case1']=np.nan
        res['case2']=np.nan
    
    return res

z = df.set_index(['id_num', 'desc', 'case1', 'case2']).T
out = z.groupby(z.index.str.split('_').str[0], as_index=False).apply(w2l).sort_values(by=['id_num', 'desc']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**out:**

```
    id_num  desc    case1   case2   amount1 amount2 category
0   100     all     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     category
1   100     all     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     dept
2   100     all     100.0   101.0   NaN     NaN     total
3   101     east    NaN     NaN     122.0   212.0   category
4   101     east    NaN     NaN     112.0   345.0   dept
5   101     east    432.0   565.0   7991.0  212.0   total
6   102     west    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     category
7   102     west    NaN     NaN     323.0   656.0   dept
8   102     west    215.0   646.0   989.0   327.0   total
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Split `df` into 3 others dataframes for `total`, `category`, `dept`,
2. Apply modifications: add column `category` and rename columns,
3. Combine all 3 dataframes to obtain the wanted result.

```
MAPPINGS = {
    'total_sal1': 'amount1',
    'total_sal2': 'amount2',
    'category1_1': 'amount1',
    'category1_2': 'amount2',
    'dept1_1': 'amount1',
    'dept1_2': 'amount2',
}

IDX_COLS = ['id_num', 'desc']
TOT_COLS = ['total_sal1', 'total_sal2', 'case1', 'case2']
CAT_COLS = ['category1_1', 'category1_2']
DPT_COLS = ['dept1_1', 'dept1_2']
NEW_COLS = IDX_COLS + ['category', 'amount1', 'amount2', 'case1', 'case2']

tot = df[IDX_COLS + TOT_COLS].assign(category='total').rename(columns=MAPPINGS)
cat = df[IDX_COLS + CAT_COLS].assign(category='category').rename(columns=MAPPINGS)
dpt = df[IDX_COLS + DPT_COLS].assign(category='dept').rename(columns=MAPPINGS)

out = pd.concat([tot, cat, dpt])[NEW_COLS].sort_index()
```

```
>>> out
   id_num  desc  category  amount1  amount2  case1  case2
0     100   all     total      NaN      NaN  100.0  101.0
0     100   all  category      NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
0     100   all      dept      NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
1     101  east     total   7991.0    212.0  432.0  565.0
1     101  east  category    122.0    212.0    NaN    NaN
1     101  east      dept    112.0    345.0    NaN    NaN
2     102  west     total    989.0    327.0  215.0  646.0
2     102  west  category      NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
2     102  west      dept    323.0    656.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: easier to understand but you have to create mapping individually. +1

Comment: I know but it was to illustrate the concept of [Split-Apply-Combine] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) without `groupby` and` apply`. I knew someone else would give a solution with this method (and more) ;-) +1